# No spec provided even if it has json file generated

Tags: go, swagger

I am trying to implement swagger with go and I am using go package `swag` for that. Not encountered any error. I am able to see swagger UI but it doesn't have specs in it even if I have generated a file in code.

I have installed a http-swagger package of go and added it to routes as mentioned in the document in https://github.com/swaggo/http-swagger.

1. `go get github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag`
2. `swag init` (files created)
3. `go get -u github.com/swaggo/http-swagger`
4. followed exact same thing as documentation of package.

Comment: Can you provide some of your code

Comment: I am able to fix this. just need to import docs in main,go